# Error while using contains in XPath query

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse the following URL:
http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/technology.xml

My code is:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("http://rss.cbc.ca/lineup/technology.xml");

echo '<ul class="rss">';

$i = 0;

if( isset($_GET['filter']) ){
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $doc = $xpath->query("item/title[contains(.,'".$_GET['filter']."')] or item/description[contains(.,'".$_GET['filter']."')]");
    echo "<p>Filtering news items on '".$_GET['filter']."'</p>";

}


foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

    if($i % 2 == 0)
        $class = "even";
    else
        $class = "odd";
    echo '<li class="'.$class.'">';
    echo "<h1>".$node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue."</h1>";
    echo "<p>".$node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue."</p>";
    echo '<a href="'.$node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue.'">Link to story</a>';
    echo "</li>";
    $i = $i + 1;
}

echo "<ul>";
```

The issue that I'm having is that if I specify a filter (through a URL var), when I do the foreach later down the page, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expression is evaluated to a boolean data type (false, because your path is wrong)

If you want to select those `item` elements having `title` or `description` children containg some string, use:

```
/rss/channel/item[(title|description)[contains(.,'string')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First: `$xpath->query` returns a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which does not have a method `getElementsByTagName`.

Second: Your query returns the `title` element or the `description` and not the `item`.

Change it to `//item[contains(title,'".$_GET['filter']."')]`